# PHP. Массив результатов поиска подстрок по регулярным выражениям

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить массив с результатами поиска подстрок по регулярному выражению?
В частности, есть вот такой текст (здесь примерный кусок, на самом деле там около сотни строчек):

> u041d\u0430\u0432\u0441\u0435\u0433\u0434\u0430", e, "id": nsions": {"height": 1349, "width": 1080}, "o2"}, "thumbnail_src": "https://imageAdress.jpg", "thumbnail_resources": [], "is_video": false, "code": "BW227651, "display_src": "https://https://imageAdress.jpg.jpg", "caption": "\u0415\u0449\u0451 \u043d\u0435\u043c\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e и т.д.

И из него нужно вычленить все ссылки и записать их в массив.

Что есть на данный момент:

```
<?php
$str = '<ТЕКСТ ИЗ ПРИМЕРА ВЫШЕ>';

preg_match_all("#https://(.*).jpg#", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

К сожалению, в результате выполнения вместо вывода ссылок поштучно, будет выведена строка начиная с первого вхождения "https" и заканчивая последним ".jpg", т.е.

> https://imageAdress.jpg", "thumbnail_resources": [], "is_video": false, "code": "BW227651, "display_src": "https://https://imageAdress.jpg.jpg

Заранее большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Существует "жадный" тип поиска и "ленивый". В первом случае регулярка "захватывает" подстроки как можно большей длины, во втором - как можно меньшей. [Вот неплохая статья на эту тему](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-greedy-and-lazy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с шаблоном

```
$str = 'u041d\u0430\u0432\u0441\u0435\u0433\u0434\u0430", e, "id": nsions": {"height": 1349, "width": 1080}, "o2"}, "thumbnail_src": "https://imageAdress.jpg", "thumbnail_resources": [], "is_video": false, "code": "BW227651, "display_src": "https://https://imageAdress.jpg.jpg", "caption": "\u0415\u0449\u0451 \u043d\u0435\u043c\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e';

preg_match_all('~https?://[^"]+~', $str, $matches);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($matches); echo '</pre>';
/* Результат:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://imageAdress.jpg
            [1] => https://https://imageAdress.jpg.jpg
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: @BondBill подправил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло!